# Is it possible to have Excel Interop's AutoFit disregard Hidden Rows?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

On the spreadsheet I'm creating, I hide certain rows:

```
if (_hide)
{
    var hiddenRange = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[_curDescriptionTopRow, ITEMDESC_COL], _xlSheet.Cells[_lastRowAdded, TOTALS_COL]];
    hiddenRange.EntireRow.Hidden = true;
}
```

I subsequently (after all the rows have been added, both the visible and the hidden, AutoFit / right-size the columns) right-width them:

```
_xlSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
```

However, this autofitting (oddly, I think) takes into account hidden column vals, too. I want it to disregard the hidden vals. Is this possible?

Comment: I doubt it. Not in a straightforward way. You could try some clunky workaround if you really wanted....

Comment: "Dang it!" <= Kip Dynamite.

Comment: How I solved this dilemma was to alter the width of the column after AutoFitting; see my auto-answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677137/how-to-wrap-merged-excel-content-beyond-a-specified-length-c if interested.